# Delta indexes not working on servers when using Thinking Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx, delta, delta-index

I'm using delta indexing for my Thinking Sphinx indexes in my Rails project. In my machine (Mac OS X) it's working fine. I change a record and it immediately finds it. On the servers (Debian) it doesn't.

I did run a sql query for delta = true and the I've got the expected recently changed records, so that part is working. In the log/searchd.query.log I see the proper request:

```
[Fri Oct 22 10:25:29.193 2010] 0.000 sec [all/3/rel 0 (0,20)] [customer_core,customer_delta] Jonas4
```

Any ideas what else could it be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer here, even though you've posted to the support list as well...

Which user is running the TS rake tasks? And which user owns the Rails site on your server? They should be the same.

Also: are you using Passenger? If so, you'll want to make sure the bin_path setting is set in your `config/sphinx.yml` file. The documentation [runs through both points](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/common_issues.html#deltas).

Let me know if neither of these things help matters.

Comment: I'm not seeing the mails appear in the support list. I've never got a reply from anybody in there and the last mail I see is from May 2008; I've assumed it's dead but I kept giving it a chance.

Comment: Yeap, the user was the problem. Thanks. Now my question is how do I make the capistrano tasks sudo to the correct username.

Comment: Really, you shouldn't be deploying as root - it should be done as the site owner, just like the rake tasks. But if you want to write your own capistrano tasks to work around this, be my guest.

Comment: Also: the mailing list is quite active - the early posts from May and June 2008 is flagged, but below them, there's entries from the last few days.

Comment: I'm not deciding on which user to deploy on, but if I was deciding, I would do it as my own user, which would cause the same issue.